# Parent Parent Next Child Child selector?

Tags: jquery-selectors, parent-child

How can I simplify this jquery selector?
**$(this).parent().parent().next().children().children().slideDown('normal');**

It works but I want to learn on how to improve it.
Thanks!
:)

**Update:** Here is the code sample.

```
<tr>
    <td><div class="LinkHeader accordionButton">TRAINING VIDEOS<span class="right"></span></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Content of Training Videos -->
    <td align="left" valign="top">
    <div class="accordionContent"> (I want to select this div)
        <div id="yunero"></div>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your markup, it would be shorter (and arguably clearer) to write:

```
$(this).closest("tr").next().find(".accordionContent").slideDown();
```

Here, [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will walk the ancestor chain and match the first `<tr>` element it finds, then [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will match its immediate next sibling, and finally [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) with a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) will return the `<div>` element you're interested in.

In passing, note that strictly speaking there is no `"normal"` duration for animations. The only supported strings are `"fast"` (200 ms) and `"slow"` (600 ms), and any other string will be interpreted as 400 ms, as if you had omitted the argument altogether. For instance, `slideDown("superFast")` will behave exactly the same as `slideDown("normal")` or plain `slideDown()`.